# IntelliJ does not recognize fillStateContainer, getDefaultState(), or getPlacementHorizontalFacing() Forge 1.16.5

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am making a custom two block long model called "littleguys:operating_table" and I watched tutorials to make it face the direction I want when it is placed. I made a custom OperatingTable class here:

```
package com.soliid.littleguys.blocks;

import net.minecraft.block.*;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.item.BlockItemUseContext;
import net.minecraft.state.StateContainer;
import net.minecraftforge.common.ToolType;

public class OperatingTable extends HorizontalBlock
{
    public OperatingTable()
    {
        super(AbstractBlock.Properties.of(Material.STONE)
            .harvestLevel(1)
                .harvestTool(ToolType.PICKAXE)
                .sound(SoundType.STONE)
                .requiresCorrectToolForDrops()
                .strength(3.5f, 4.0f)
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void fillStateContainer (StateContainer.Builder<Block, BlockState> builder)
    {
        builder.add(FACING);
    }

    @Override
    public BlockState getStateForPlacement(BlockItemUseContext context) {
        return this.getDefaultState().with(FACING, context.getPlacementHorizontalFacing().getOpposite());
    }
}
```

The @Override gives me an error reading
`Method does not override method from its superclass`, getDefaultState() gives me `Cannot resolve method 'getDefaultState' in 'OperatingTable'`, and getPlacementHorizontalFacing() gives me `Cannot resolve method 'getPlacementHorizontalFacing' in 'BlockItemUseContext'`.

I now realized that these methods are not in OperatingTables's superclasses (HorizontalBlock and Block) but I want to know which methods are now used instead. There are no errors in the registry of `RegistryObject<Block> OPERATING_TABLE` or `RegistryObject<Item> OPERATING_TABLE_ITEM`.

This class is not complete but I cannot continue until I resolve the error.

Comment: Note: only the first @Override method gives me an error, not the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1.16.5 you have to use

```
@Override
protected void createBlockStateDefinition(StateContainer.Builder<Block, BlockState> builder) {
    builder.add(FACING);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public BlockState getStateForPlacement(BlockItemUseContext context) {
    return super.getStateForPlacement(context).setValue(FACING, context.getHorizontalDirection().getOpposite());
                                              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities, but most cases are cache issue.
Please try invalidate cache and restart IntelliJ.
If issue persist, then sync Gradle project manually.

Answer (score -1):

In build.gradle, on line 34, `mappings` is defined as `channel: 'official', version: '1.16.5'`. This should be changed to `channel: 'snapshot', version: '[snapshot version]'`. The version I used was `'20210309-1.16.5'`. Then, rebuild the gradle in Terminal using `gradlew genIntellijRuns`.